# A special case of duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

The problem I am facing is the following, and I wonder if there is a clever way to approach it.

**Simplified Example**:

```
dum1 = pd.DataFrame([[123,234,0],
                 [234,345,456],
                 [345,567,0],
                 [678,0,0]],
               index=[0,1,2,3],columns=['phone1','phone2','phone3'])
```

The real case has over 30,000 entries and maybe 10 columns of phone numbers. Entries should be considered duplicates if they have a common phone number "directly" or "indirectly". i.e. in this dataframe, direct duplicates are lines with index 0 and 1, and lines with 1 and 2, and indirect duplicates are lines with index 0,1,2 since first and third entry are linked through second (zeros should not have a part in the duplicate definition).

**Expected output**:

```
dum2 = pd.DataFrame([[123,234,345,456,567],
                 [123,234,345,456,567],
                 [123,234,345,456,567],
                 [678,0,0,0,0]],
               index=[0,1,2,3],columns=['phone1','phone2','phone3','phone4','phone5'])
```

With all the duplicates having the same phone numbers which is the union of the phone numbers of each one (with extra phone columns added if needed).

I run Windows 64, Python Version: 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:07:13) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
Pandas Version: 0.18.1

Comment: I'm not sure how useful pandas is here.  I would maybe start with a list of sets and see how far that gets you.

Comment: A rough outline of the top of my head: Iterate over your rows using `iterrows`, compare subsequent rows, set an auxiliary boolen column that is `True` e.g. if the current row and the following row should be combined and `False` if they should not. Then you can do a second iteration to somehow combine all successive rows that are `True`. It's not fast because of the two iterations, but I think it would work.